# How can I get the Xcode linker to remove duplicate symbols it finds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang, xcframework

So I recently converted a universal/fat framework to an XCFramework and I need to replace the old framework with the new XCFramework in an app.

The app had the below linker flags:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC -force_load path/to/FrameworkName.framework/Versions/A/FrameworkName -lstdc++
```

Migrating to XCFramework, in order to use the correct framework inside the XCFramework, I figured it would make sense to do the following:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphoneos*] = -ObjC -force_load path/to/FrameworkName.xcframework/ios-arm64/FrameworkName.framework/Versions/A/FrameworkName -lstdc++
OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = -ObjC -force_load path/to/FrameworkName.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/FrameworkName.framework/Versions/A/FrameworkName -lstdc++
```

On building, Xcode could not find the XCFramework's headers, most likely because FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS (which we've historically used) does not work with XCFrameworks. So I also added the XCFramework to the "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase in order to get Xcode to find the headers.

Here comes the problem. Xcode now tells me that there are duplicate symbols, probably because I added the XCFramework to the "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase and also force-loaded the internal static library using linker flags. I have to do the latter so that the entire contents of the static library will be linked, but I also had to do the former because Xcode could not find the headers otherwise.

Is there a way (maybe another linker flag) to get the Xcode linker to remove duplicate symbols it finds? Or as an alternative, is there a way I can get Xcode to find XCFramework headers without having to add the XCFramework to the "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase?

I should also add that removing the -ObjC linker flag fixes the problem, but I don't want to risk breaking anything in the other frameworks being linked (since the flag links Objective-C code that static analysis cannot resolve as being called directly). I'm willing to provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to list the framework in OTHER_LDFLAGS at all. You should just add the xcframework to "Link Binary With Libraries" and remove it from OTHER_LDFLAGS. The whole point of xcframeworks is you don't need to provide the full internal path to the correct architecture.

This has nothing to do with the `-ObjC` flag. That still goes in your OTHER_LDFLAGS. Note that this is redundant with `-force_load`. `-force_load` was a workaround for a bug prior to Xcode 4. See [QA1490](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1490/_index.html) for details. The workaround recommendation was removed in 2014.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried removing the `-force_load` flag but the app develops a runtime error and crashes. Is it possible there are certain things that just don't get linked unless we force-load the static library?

Comment: Yes, though it shouldn't impact the normal case of ObjC categories.

Comment: The `-ObjC` flag was meant for the other frameworks being linked to the app, in order to link Objective-C code that the linker would otherwise discard e.g. categories. It seems the framework of interest would need to be force-loaded though, in order to get its entire contents linked (otherwise the app would crash as observed).
Is it possible to do both and avoid duplicate symbols?

Comment: yes, unless you actually have duplicate symbols. If you're just getting duplicate symbols due to linking the same framework twice (once in OTHER_LDFLAGS where it should not be, and once in "Link Binary With Library" where it should be), then just removing it from OTHER_LDFLAGS should be enough. If, however, you have done something like linking the same dependency statically in two frameworks, then that's an error. You avoid duplicate symbols by not doing that.

Comment: For example (just to pick a case that happens a lot), if FrameworkName statically links (or otherwise embeds) OpenSSL, and your app also statically links OpenSSL, then you'll get a ton of duplicate symbols for OpenSSL. That is correct, and the fix is to not embed OpenSSL into FrameworkName. But if that's not the problem, and it's just that you're linking FrameworkName twice, just remove it from OTHER_LDFLAGS. `-force_load` will still apply if it's there.